# NodeJS 'assert' test fails for json object returned through the express http response

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

Having recently developed an interest in NodeJS, I finally managed to get my hands on a NodeJS book. A simple example on the book was to create an express server and write a test to verify a simple API exposed as part of the exercise.

Please refer to the following code (I am using node v0.8.8)

The Server (nodeExample.js)

```
     var express = require('express')
     var app = express.createServer()
     app.listen(8000)
     var msgs = []

     app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Welcome to Node Twitter')
     })

     app.post('/send', express.bodyParser(), function(req, res) {
        if (req.body && req.body.tweet) {
           msgs.push(req.body.tweet)
           res.send({status:"ok", message:"Message received"})
        } else {
            res.send({status:"nok", message:"Message not received"})
        }
    })

    app.get('/tweets', function(req,res) {
    res.send(msgs)
    })
```

The Test

```
var http = require('http'),
assert = require('assert')
var opts = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/send',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}

var req = http.request(opts, function(res) {
 res.setEncoding('utf8')
 var data = "";
res.on('data', function(d) {
  data += d
})
res.on('end', function() {
  assert.strictEqual(data, {status:"ok", message:"Message received"})
 })
})

req.write('tweet=test')
req.end()
```

I managed to get the server up and running without issues ( Except for a warning that the createServer method of 
express is deprecated , although doesn't seem to be what's bothering me ) ; but when I run the test, assert throws an exception indicating test failing, which should obviously not happen.

Here's a screenshot of the problem

[image]

If you observe the error closely it seems to be the escape characters "\n" appended in parts of the response, that seem to be causing the problem.

I tried to circumvent the issue by

1. trying different equality checks (equal , strictEqual and deepEqual)
2. removing the utf8 encoding from the response

but had no luck ( unless I ofcourse perform an equality check with stringified test data, against the stringified response object returned where the formatting has been manually removed ).

So the question is,

1. Why is the response formatted in the above manner ? Was it only for readability ?
2. Assuming I am not allowed to remove the formatting, how can I perform an assert test on the response data I just received.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reply you get from your server is a JSON string:

```
'{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Tweet received"
}'
```

You are comparing this to an object:

```
{status:"ok", message:"Message received"}
```

Since I gather you want to assert you get the correct reply, I suggest you `JSON.parse` the reply first, and compare the two objects with `assert.deepEqual`:

```
assert.deepEqual(JSON.parse(data), {status:"ok", message:"Message received"})
```

This is probably a wiser way than comparing a string to an object.

Comment: That was embarassing. Thank you very much for taking the time to help :-)

Comment: No problem! Btw, the reason you get `\n` and spaces in your JSON is the Express [`json spaces`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings) setting. In production, you won't get formatted JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

```
res.on('end', function(){
  assert.deepEqual(JSON.parse(data), {"status": "ok", "message": "Tweet received"});
});

if (req.body && req.body.tweet) {
    tweets.push(req.body.tweet);
    console.log("success:" + req.body.tweet);
    res.send({"status": "ok", "message": "Tweet received"});
} else {...
```

Comment: Please improve your answer - e.g. highlight syntax; add some details/explanation.